# Does the functionality of email forwarding from an old address to a new one exist?

Tags: yahoo-mail, email-forwarding, email-rules

I've had one email address on Yahoo for several years and I want to make a new Yahoo email address. I do have many contacts currently. The obvious, but slower way of letting my contacts know about my new address would just be to send them a mass email informing them or responding as needed.

Is there a function within Yahoo, that if a contact emails me, it informs them that I'm not using that email address anymore and here is the new address?

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo mail offers this as a feature of [Mail Plus](http://mailplus.mail.yahoo.com/) that is available at an extra cost.

Answer (score 1):

Without paying for Mail Plus, you have two options:

- Create an extra email address instead of a separate account.

  You can do this in *Options → Mail Accounts → Additional Email Adress*.
- Enable auto-response.

  In *Options → Vacation Response*, you can configure an automatic response that tells everyone who sends you an email that your address has changed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change your old account to a paid account to get mail forwarding.  Don't know if they have an "on vacation" function.

Answer (score -1):

I know that it works with gmail.  All one has yo do is simply enter their old email's pop3/ imap/ smpt info and you can send and receive from said old email as well as the new one. I'd say get a gmail account and use that anyways.